# Replace NAs in a window around a value

Tags: r, na, zoo

My zoo data looks like below. This data is part of a larger zoo (time series) data set.

```
 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 
NA NA NA NA NA  1 NA NA NA NA NA  3 NA NA NA

 library(zoo)    
 x <- zoo(c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 3, NA, NA, NA, NA))
```

I want to replace NAs in a window around each non-NA value with the non-NA value. For example, a window of [EDIT] 5 around the non-NA would look like this:

```
 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 
NA NA NA  1  1  1  1  1 NA  3  3  3  3  3 NA
```

I can do what I want with a long and messy set of `ifelse` statements.

Is there a better way? I looked at zoo's NA fill set of functions but did not see anything for a window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess rolling apply will do the job?

```
> rollapply(x, 5, function(x){mean(x[!is.na(x)])}, fill=NA)
  1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12  13  14  15  16 
 NA  NA NaN   1   1   1   1   1 NaN   3   3   3   3   3  NA  NA
```

Comment: This indeed does the job. The zoo documentation says na.pad = TRUE is now deprecated and use fill = NA instead.

Answer (score 0):

We could also use `filter`

```
v2 <- stats::filter(replace(v1,is.na(v1),0), rep(1,5))
is.na(v2) <- !v2
```

Comment: This solution also does the job. Not quite as intuitive as the other solution. As stated on the question, these data are part of a bigger data set. For this solution, cbind the v2 vector to the other data.